# jQuery - Double-colon in JSON URL

Tags: jquery, ezpublish

For a project I'm building in EZPublish I'm using the EZJScore module to generate JSON arrays. Ezjscore requires me to seperate parameters with double colons, for example:

> http://[domain]/ezjscore/call/news::cat::3

After hours of testing I concluded that jquery can't parse URL's with double colons in it. At least the `getjson` and `ajax` functions can't handle this...

Does anybody know a solution or fix to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you need. You want jQuery to parse the result of http://[domain]/ezjscore/call/news::cat::3, not the url string itself, right ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery `post` function by hijacking the submit of your form, and make sure to return JSON in your ezjscore php function. Something like this:

```
$.post($(this).attr('action') + '/ezjscore/call/', 'news::cat::3, function (data) {},'json');
```